# MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT INCLUDE NULL

Tags: mysql, database, group-concat

I use this code to group the equipment, but when the id_material has no equipment the id_material didn't show.

```
select
material.id_material, 
material.mat_part_number, 
group_concat(distinct equipment.equipment_name order by equipment.equipment_name separator ', ') as equipment    
FROM material   
INNER JOIN equipment_list ON material.id_material=equipment_list.PKid_material INNER JOIN equipment ON equipment_list.PKid_equipment=equipment.id_equipment group by id_material;
```

i want it to appear like this

```
+-------------+----------------+
| id_material | equipment      |                                                             
+-------------+----------------+
|     1000001 | eq1            |         
|     1000002 | eq1, eq2       |
|     1000003 | eq3            |
|     1000004 |                |                           
+-------------+----------------+
```

but it only appear this

```
+-------------+----------------+
| id_material | equipment      |                                                             
+-------------+----------------+
|     1000001 | eq1            |         
|     1000002 | eq1, eq2       |
|     1000003 | eq3            |                        
+-------------+----------------+
```

where should i put the NULL condition?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Add `HAVING equipment <> ''` at the end.

Comment: I am sorry I am new on Stack Over Flow and still confused about format the code :( Can you tell me where should I learn?

Comment: if i put `HAVING equipment <> ' ' `  at the end, the id_material that doesn't has the equipment_name doesn't show up.

Comment: You need to change `INNER JOIN equipment_list` to `LEFT JOIN equipment_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your query, this might help you.

```
SELECT 
  material.id_material, 
  material.mat_part_number, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT equipment.equipment_name 
    ORDER BY 
      equipment.equipment_name SEPARATOR ', '
  ) AS equipment 
FROM 
  material 
  LEFT JOIN equipment_list ON material.id_material = equipment_list.PKid_material 
  LEFT JOIN equipment ON equipment_list.PKid_equipment = equipment.id_equipment 
GROUP BY 
  id_material;
```